# Integration Symbol with Limits

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[image]

How can I write the integration symbol in latex as shown in the picture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \int_{\substack{a\\\mathcal{P}}}^b (\nabla ...)
\]

\[
  \int\limits_{\substack{a\\\mathcal{P}}}^b (\nabla ...)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A reasonably accurate reproduction of the screen shot you posted is shown below.

Note the use of `\mathbf` for `a` and `b`, the use of `\mathcal` for `P`, the "invisible" first row in the `\substack` to push the entire lower-limit group down a bit, and the `\!` (negative thinspace) directive in front of `\substack` to move the lower-limit group a bit to the left:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{\!\substack{\phantom{x}\\ \mathbf{a}\\ \mathcal{P}}}^{\mathbf{b}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

If you're not interested in a literal copy of the screen shot you posted but just in how to enter an integral symbol with limits, you could get by with writing

```
\int_{<lower limit>}^{<upper limit>}
```

Answer (score 11):

Not a symbol I would use; but here it is, with a definition that allows easier syntax and detaches the “P” from the lower limit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\Pint}{%
  \mathrlap{\mathop{\phantom{\int}}\limits_{\!\mathcal{P}}}%
  \!\int
}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}}
\Pint_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

The first `\int` is just for comparing the placement of symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Some attempts using `\underset`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\huge
\[
\mathbf{
\underset{\mathcal{P}}{\phantom{P}\int_{\!a}^{b}} 
\underset{\mathcal{P}}{\int_a^b}
\underset{\!\mathcal{P}}{\int_{\!a}^{b}} 
\int_{\!\underset{\mathcal{P}}a}^b 
\intop_{\underset{\mathcal{P}}{a}}^{b}
}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key problem of the OP here is to stack the subscript \rho (the weird P) UNDER subscript a. To achieve this, use the command `\substack` as demonstrated below in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\substack{
            a\\
            \rho}}^b
     (\bigtriangledown
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The symbol below the `a` looks more like a calligraphic uppercase `P` than the Greek lowercase `rho`.